# Is it possible to show processing message with time elapse

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

Currently i am showing "Processing your Request please wait..." when the user click the submit button or anchor button.Its working fine.

Is it possible to show processing time decrease something like start with some 120 seconds and decrease as during processing.

My code as below:

```
function on_process(){
     var y = document.getElementById("msg").style.display = "block";
    return true;
}

<form name="searchForm" method=post action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/servlet/libilityController" onsubmit="javascript:return validate()&& on_process();">
<p id="msg" style="display:none">Please wait request is processing....</p>
```

Not sure how to do in the `<p>` tag any body help on this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is processing done on the client or on the server?

Comment: processing on server side

Comment: Is this using an Ajax call?  The code you've shown here appears to be a regular form POST request.  I'm asking because on a regular POST it's not going to matter much; the whole page will go away when submit is clicked.

Comment: No it is using Ajax.Its simple Javascript on Jsp with servlet as controller

Comment: so... you just want some count-down which has nothing to do with the real time left?

Comment: yes just want some count down

Comment: any body give example how to solve